# подсказка в ячейке таблицы

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как сделать, чтобы при наведении курсора мыши на ячейку таблицы, возникала подсказка, я нашел код в интернете

```html
<table width="717" border="0">
  <tr>
   <td >
    <p class="tt" id='bonus_1'>
   При наведение курсора на <a class="tooltip" href="#"  onmouseover="document.getElementById('bonus_1').style.display='block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('bonus_1').style.display='none';">этот текст<span id="bonus_1" class="hovertip">Вот и всплывающая подсказка</span></a> появится всплывающая подсказка. 
    </p>
   </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

но он не рабочий. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря что вы хотите видеть в качестве всплывающей подсказки. Можете использовать хинты показываемые браузером с использованием атрибута `title`, а можете воспользоваться множеством плагинов тултипов, в частности, например, взять таковой из бутстрапа, или же написать  свой, но для этого надо понимать, как работает html и js, а не просто скопировать код с интернета в надежде, что свершиться чудо.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td title="текст подсказки">ячейка таблицы</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Нет мне нужно сложнее , мне нужно чтобы подсказка была в "маленьком окошке" типа hint.

Answer (score 0):

Пример не рабочий, потому что у вас на странице два элемента имеют `id="bonus_1"` если отсюда

```
<p class="tt" id='bonus_1'>
```

его убрать, то все будет работать

```css
#bonus_1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table width="717" border="0">
  <tr>
   <td >
    <p class="tt">
   При наведение курсора на <a class="tooltip" href="#"  onmouseover="document.getElementById('bonus_1').style.display='block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('bonus_1').style.display='none';">этот текст<span id="bonus_1" class="hovertip">Вот и всплывающая подсказка</span></a> появится всплывающая подсказка. 
    </p>
   </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```